# How to work with controls inside a user control from a shared (static) DependencyPropertyChangedCallback in WPF?

Tags: .net, wpf

I'm quite a beginner in WPF. I worked myself through a few tutorials and now I wanted to try my first own project and am stuck right at the beginning.

I try to create a user control with a bindable property `Items`.

The user control's XAML contains just a simple `TextBox`, nothing else.

```
<UserControl x:Class="UserControl1" xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestControl" ...>
    <TextBox x:Name="txtContent" />
</UserControl>
```

In the code behind of the user control I created a `DependencyProperty` called `Items`.

```
Public Shared ReadOnly ItemsProperty As DependencyProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Items", GetType(IList(Of String)), GetType(MyUserControl), New FrameworkPropertyMetadata(Nothing, AddressOf MyUserControl.OnItemsChanged))

Public Property Items As IList(Of String)
    Get
        Return MyBase.GetValue(MyUserControl.ItemsProperty)
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As IList(Of String))
        MyBase.SetValue(MyUserControl.ItemsProperty, value)
    End Set
End Property

Private Shared Sub OnItemsChanged(sender As DependencyObject, e As DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs)
    ...
End Sub
```

In the `OnItemsChanged` procedure I'd like to add the content of the items collection to the `TextBox` of the user control. But since the DependencyProperty is `Shared` (`static` for C# users) and the user control itself is not I don't know how to get a grip of the `TextBox` inside my user control and work with it.

I tried to call a non-shared procedure in the setter of the .NET property, but this .NET property seems to be only cosmetic and of no use.

I also tried to cast the `sender` to `UserControl` and get the `Content` of the user control (which should be my `TextBox`). But the `Content` is always `Nothing` (`null` for C# users).

So, how do I work with controls inside my user control from the static DependencyPropertyChangedCallback?

Comment: Insulting c# users while you use VB isn't the best way to get assistance.

Comment: If you read carefully, then you'll see, that's it's not an insult, it's pity or sympathy...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After stripping down my test project to the essentials everything I tried before without success (casting the sender to `UserControl` and getting it's `Content` or casting the sender to the specific control type and getting the `TextBox` by it's name) suddenly worked.
Then I did the stripping down again step by step until I found the step, after that the problem disappeared.

The problem was, that I created a UserControl file named "TestControl.xaml" but the UserControl tag inside this file still had the attribute `x:class="UserControl1"`.
I could use this control with it's proper name (TestControl) in the MainWindow, I could compile my project and I could debug my project, but apparently this prevented to work with the user control in the code behind.
So, renaming the attribute `x:class="UserControl1"` to `x:class="TestControl"` did the trick.